# Using recursion, segregate an array of integers to have the even integers come before the odd

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I need to use recursion that takes in array of integers and has the even integers appear before the odd integers i.e an array of [1,2,3,4,5] should look like [2,4,1,3,5]. Please note that the integers do not need to be in any specific order just even before odd. Here is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated!

```
public class EBOMain {

   static int[] Array  = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   static int n;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.print("Array before sort: "  );
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(Array[i] +" ");
        n = Array.length;
        rearrange(Array, n);

        System.out.print("\nArray after sort: "  );
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++)
            System.out.print(Array[i] +" ");        
    }

    public static void rearrange(int []Array,int n){
          if (n==0)
            return;
        else if(Array[n-1]%2==0) {
            for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++) {
                if(Array[i]%2!=0) {      
                    int temp = Array[i];
                    Array[i]= Array[n-1];
                    Array[n-1] = temp;

                    rearrange(Array,n-1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
            rearrange(Array,n-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I did want to arrange the new array into a specific order how would I go about it? So again I am given the array [1,2,3,4,5] and now I want it in the specific order the evens come before odds but both even and odd in ascending order so the new array would have to appear as [2,4,1,3,5]. Again I need to use recursion.

Comment: @JosephV It would be best to ask that in a new question. You can post a link to this one for reference.

Comment: @ModusTollens would I just copy and paste the url into the question box or is there another way to link it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JosephV You can use the share link beneath the question to get a link to it (the same goes for answers). You can copy and paste that link. Questions are supposed to stand on their own, so it is important to post the code showing what you tried as well.

Comment: @ModusTollens ok I will take a crack at it tomorrow when I get up, It is 1am here, getting a little tired. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @JosephV No problem, you're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `n` with the length of the array in the first call to `rearrange`. See this corrected code. Make sure you use Java code conventions; I renamed the `Array`variable to `array`.

```
public class EBOMain {

    static int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("array before sort: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }

        rearrange(array, array.length);  // <-- Change is here

        System.out.print("\narray after sort: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void rearrange(int[] array, int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return;
        } else if (array[n - 1] % 2 == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                if (array[i] % 2 != 0) {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[n - 1];
                    array[n - 1] = temp;

                    rearrange(array, n - 1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            rearrange(array, n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array before sort: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
array after sort: 6 2 4 1 3 5
```